# s3 upload from base64 using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(new_string)
filename = 'image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

It saves a file as jpg and I can open it.

How can I upload this to s3 bucket, or any other service, and return a URL Security is not an issue.

I tried

```
    try:
    convertedFileString = fstring.replace('-', '+').replace('_','/').replace(',','=')
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(new_string)
     # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket = s3.Bucket('ag-grid')
        bucket.put_object(Key=filename, Body=f)
except Exception as e:
    return {
            'statusCode': 500,  
            'body': str(e)
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen the boto 3 documentation? http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not sure if I understand your problem.

I use the code below to upload and it's working.

```
            # Filename
            new_name = '{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}x{}.{}'.format(cid, uid, id_service_order, id_question, uuid.uuid4(), 0, 0,
                                                        fileExtension)  # type: str
            key = "{}".format(new_name)
            # Let's use Amazon S3
            s3 = boto3.client("s3",
                              aws_access_key_id=aws_config.aws_access_key_id,
                              aws_secret_access_key=aws_config.aws_secret_access_key,
                              region_name=aws_config.aws_s3_region,
                              config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

            dec = base64.b64decode(img_base64)
            rs = s3.put_object(
                Bucket=aws_config.aws_s3_bucket,
                Key=key,
                ContentType=fileType,
                Body=dec,
                ACL='public-read'
            )
            print(rs)
            print(new_name)
```

Does that help you?